# How to display "Links" / "Update Links" dialog in PowerPoint with VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In Excel, this should be done easily (although form me it doesn't work for some reason):

> ThisWorkbook.Parent.Dialogs(xlDialogOpenLinks).Show

or simply

> Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpenLinks).Show

But how can I accomplish that under PowerPoint?
The PowerPoint.Application.Dialogs property does not exist and cannot be called at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the slide and slide shapes, testing if the shape is a linked object or a linked picture etc. and listing out the LinkFormat.SourceFullName.
You could then amend the LinkFormat.SourceFullName.
See example here:
 [Edit links in Powerpoint VBA](https://exceloffthegrid.com/edit-links-in-powerpoint-using-vba/)

Comment: Doing that already. Not amending, but processing. But if any problems occur, I want the user to be able to fix it, just as he could with the Excel "Update Links" dialog. Only wanna re-write that functionality if there are no other solutions.

Comment: @JayC667 The code at that link is a decent starting point for what you want to do; from there, you'd need to test to see if the link's path points to a file that's actually there and if not, either pop an InputBox or a file dialog (the kinder/gentler way) to let the user point to the needed file, whereupon you change the link's path to the file the user chose.